# Django Admin MakeMigrations Error - ROOT_URLCONF is not configured

Tags: python, django, database, makemigrations

I'm having this error when I trying to push django-admin makemigrations from cmd in my project folder. I can not find the exact problem in other topics. I'm quite sure that I'm doing well till here. I really appreciate your helps in advance.

There is the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting ROOT_URLCONF, but settings are not 
configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call 
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

There is my urls.py module

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from apps.crm import views as crm_views

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', crm_views.home, name = 'home'),
path('about/', crm_views.about, name = 'about'),
]
```

There is my wsgi module

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
# export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proje_dosyasi.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

There is my settings module

```
    """
Django settings for proje_dosyasi project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '7u_stue$yr3&m3r!%+*!$98p2vn4&83l3mmd^j=f$5=tunsc1_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]


# Application definition

DEFAULT_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = []

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'apps.crm',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DEFAULT_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'proje_dosyasi.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates/',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'proje_dosyasi.wsgi.application'





# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

try:
    from proje_dosyasi.local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    print('Local_settings hatası alındı')
    pass
```

There is the local settings module

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you attempting to run the makemigration?

Comment: I tried django-admin makemigration and got this error. I also tried to python manage.py makemigration but it makes no changes despite of changes.